# React app freezing due to useEffect hook in 16.9 while working fine in 16.8

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, js-cookie

The code runs fine on React 16.8, yet freezes on >=16.9. I looked at the changes for 16.9 but all it mentioned was an additional *warning* when there's an infinite loop, not an actual change in behaviour, so this shouldn't be happening, yet it is.

Setting useEffect's dependency to [] does break the loop but means the code needs to be modified and I'm not sure how.

The below code can also be found in a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/389o3qyoq5). The version is set to 16.8.4 so it doesn't freeze.

index.jsx

```js
//...
import { SessionContext, getSessionCookie, setSessionCookie } from "./session";
import "./styles.css";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const LoginHandler = ({ history }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    // NOTE request to api login here instead of this fake promise
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r(), 1000));
    setSessionCookie({ email });
    history.push("/");
    setLoading(false);
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <h4>Logging in...</h4>;
  }

  return (
    //...
  );
};

const LogoutHandler = ({ history }: any) => {
  //...
};

const ProtectedHandler = ({ history }) => {
   //...
};

const Routes = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(getSessionCookie());
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setSession(getSessionCookie());
    },
    [session]
  );

  return (
    <SessionContext.Provider value={session}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <h6 style={{ display: "inline" }}>Nav Bar</h6>
          <h6 style={{ display: "inline", marginLeft: "5rem" }}>
            {session.email || "No user is logged in"}
          </h6>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginHandler} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={LogoutHandler} />
          <Route path="*" component={ProtectedHandler} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </SessionContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Routes />
  </div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

session.ts

```js
import React from "react";
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const setSessionCookie = (session: any): void => {
  Cookies.remove("session");
  Cookies.set("session", session, { expires: 14 });
};

export const getSessionCookie: any = () => {
  const sessionCookie = Cookies.get("session");

  if (sessionCookie === undefined) {
    return {};
  } else {
    return JSON.parse(sessionCookie);
  }
};

export const SessionContext = React.createContext(getSessionCookie());
```

Expected result: app functions in 16.9 just like in 16.8

Actual result: app freezes in 16.9 due to supposed infinite loop in useEffect

Error message: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON.parse(sessionCookie)` always returns a new object.

`setSession(getSessionCookie())` sets the session to that new object

`[session]` says to run whenever a new session object is set in the state (which happens every render).

So that's the infinite loop you're seeing.  To stop it you can do something like:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
      const newSessionCookie = getSessionCookie()
      if(newSessionCookie.uniqueId !== session.uniqueId) {
        setSession(getSessionCookie());
      }
    },
    [session]
  )
```

You just need to be sure you have some unique identifier for the cookie.

Comment: You could also track the prop in the dependency array. e.g. `[session.email]`. Every time the session email (or whatever prop you choose) changes, rerun this effect. This eliminates the need to read the session cookie and the if statement.

Comment: That would work if you're only using session.email.  Since the code above uses the entire session object you need to define the entire session object as a dependency.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the entire session object is being used inside the effect? This follows the same thing you're doing by checking a unique id and setting some session if that has changed. You don't need to track an entire object in the dependency array.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  However, if you don't have any logic within the effect actually using the session or session.email values you should get an unnecessary dependency linting error.

Comment: You shouldn't on `useEffect`. You will however get that warning on methods such as  `useCallback` or `useMemo`. https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-violet-nrblf

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this has created another issue; for some reason the session doesn't get set properly unless I manually navigate to a different url. I.e. the history.push fails because when trying to access the session info through the context, it comes up as an empty object.

*const ProtectedHandler = ({ history }) => {
  const session = useContext(SessionContext);
  //...
}*

The session is only properly received if I hard navigate to the page by hand.